# What affects when someone uses my pawn?

Tags: dragons-dogma

So I just picked up Dragon's Dogma a couple of days ago, and so far I love it. I'm a bit confused, though, about what factors into when other players enlist my pawn into their group. The game just gives a really unhelpful hint that says something like "encourage other players to enlist your pawn."

So exactly what does one need to do to encourage other players to use your pawn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tip is definitely unhelpful.

Everything affects whether someone uses your pawn so make sure your pawn is useful as that's really the only encouragement to offer aside from straight out sharing your ID and asking people to use your pawn (and maybe offering other incentives that way).

All of this is covered on [the wiki](http://dragonsdogma.wikia.com/wiki/Pawns) and various [forums](http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/53989/t1800742-isn-anyone-hiring-my-pawn/), but here's a rough outline of how to make a pawn useful for others and thus encouraging them to use it.

1. Friends - Pawns are most used by friends because they're free for friends so make friends with people playing the game (usually lower level than you).
2. High ratings - Opinion matters so again, make a useful pawn.
3. Good equipment - Users won't have to give (or have) better equipment for your pawn.
4. Complement of appearance, skills, vocation and inclinations - all of these affect your pawn performance and a messed up AI or build that is not useful (or worse detrimental) in combat or exploration or what have you will not earn your pawn many uses. Different builds work for different scenarios so you kind of want to pigeonhole your pawn for specific uses.
5. Knowledge - Learning to kill a variety of enemies, exploring many areas and running quests makes your pawn more helpful as well.
6. Level - People usually use pawns at or above their level because they are more useful than lower-level pawns so make sure your pawn is suited to help lower-level builds by generally applying the above in tandem with your knowledge of the game earlier than where you are at. Towards the end, this means tailoring your pawn for the harder fights.

These are all guidelines because there is no strict formula to getting someone to use your pawn over another.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It sounds like I need to get my pawn leveled up a bit more before I get serious about trying to get others to use her.

Comment: I know for me, I tended to play a ranged/melee damage class while playing through the game, so my main pawn was always my tank. It made it easier for me to deal with large groups and I was never the focus of the incoming damage. So on a fairly normal basis, I would hire on a damage Mage class and a healing Mage class from the Rift.